# Java: how can I format text on an OutputStream to the width of the user's console?

Tags: java, text, console, word-wrap, outputstream

Specifically, I would like text sent to the user's OutputStream to have word wrapping so that when text continues onto a new line, words are not broken up. So instead of this:

```
The quick brown fox j
umps over the lazy do
g.
```

It will show up in the console like this:

```
The quick brown fox 
jumps over the lazy 
dog.
```

One option I know of is to write a method like this one to wrap text to a specific character width:

```
wrapText(String text, int width)
```

But I'd rather have the text just wrap automatically to the current width of the user's console. Is there any way to do this? Any objects in java that might help me? Thanks!

Comment: To start with, you should be thinking about a `Writer`, not an `OutputStream`. An `OutputStream` deals with *binary* data, not text. (To write text, you'd typically wrap an `OutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` or something similar.)

Comment: @Jon: `PrintStream` (like the one obtained from `System.out`) can deal with character data directly (potential characters encoding issues not considered).

Comment: @Jon: Ok, so I'm on the right track. I have the OutputStream wrapped in a PrintWriter right now but I'm not sure whether that's the Writer I should be using to solve this problem.

Comment: @BalusC: PrintStream can, but shouldn't generally be used anyway IMO, given the way it swallows errors...

Comment: @torjinx: I would actually make your class take a `Writer` itself - then the *caller* can decide to use a `PrintWriter` to wrap an `OutputStream` if they really want to.

Answer (score 3):

A [BreakIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html#line) would help you determine where to break lines and from there it would be easy go to doing the actual line breaking yourself.

However, I don't see how you'd determine (automatically, cross-platform) the width of the user's console.

Answer (score 2):

To get the width of the console, you can use the [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) library.  It's not pure Java and has some native code, but has the functionality you need and works on Windows, Max and Linux.

In JLine, to get the console width use the [Terminal](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jline/Terminal.html) class and call `getTerminalWidth()`.

Comment: Will JLine work if I'm trying to detect the width of the user's console over a socket?

Comment: @torjinx Do you mean over SSH/Telnet?  Yes it does.